# getting at the right parts of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a way to solve my problem, but it seems like there should be something better.  Also I realize that I probably don't have a good enough handle on how to get at parts of lists the way I need to. I'm doing the following, which gets me the result I need:

```
x = {
   {{"a", "b", "c"}, 12},
   {{"q", "b", "c"}, 32},
   {{"w", "b", "c"}, 11},
   {{"a", "b", "d"}, 22}
   };

GatherBy[Partition[Flatten[x, 2], 4][[All, 2 ;;]], #[[;; 2]] &]
```

> {{{"b", "c", 12}, {"b", "c", 32}, {"b", "c", 11}}, {{"b", "d", 22}}}

I'm gathering these list elements by the 2nd and 3rd element of the first list in each row.  I want to group those numeric elements. The only way I can think of solving this is flattening the list to get rid of the "list within a list" problem.  Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map[Flatten, GatherBy[x, #[[1, 2 ;;]] &], {2}][[All, All, 2 ;;]]
```

Comment: All of the answers work well.  I "accepted" this one because it shows me a little more about accessing the proper elements in my list. There are a few others that might also do that, but I'm still trying to understand them.  Trying to understand all of these answers has been an education and a half!

Answer (score 6):

Somewhat easier to read:

```
GatherBy[Map[Rest @* Flatten, x], Most]

(* {{{"b", "c", 12}, {"b", "c", 32}, {"b", "c", 11}}, {{"b", "d", 22}}} *)
```

Pre V10 version:

```
GatherBy[Map[Composition[Rest, Flatten], x], Most]
```

Comment: The Bracket-free notation doesn't seem to gather like items.  The others work - I don't understand them yet, but they work.  I need to look up a few things before I'll understand them.

Comment: @MitchelKaplan D'oh.  My eyes aren't too good.  Thanks.

Comment: Short and for any fairly recent version: `GatherBy[Rest /@ Flatten /@ x, Most]`

Answer (score 3):

```
f = GatherBy[{##2 & @@ #1, #2} & @@@ #, Most] &;
f@x
(* {{{"b","c",12},{"b","c",32},{"b","c",11}},{{"b","d",22}}} *)
```

or

```
f2 = Gather[{##2 & @@ #1, #2} & @@@ #, Equal @@ Most /@ {##} &] &;
f2@x
(*  {{{"b","c",12},{"b","c",32},{"b","c",11}},{{"b","d",22}}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Gather[Cases[x, {{_, x__}, z_} :> {x, z}], #1[[;; 2]] == #2[[;; 2]] &]
(*{{{"b", "c", 12}, {"b", "c", 32}, {"b", "c", 11}}, {{"b", "d", 22}}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sow[{{_, a_, b_}, n_}] := Sow[{a, b, n}, h[a, b]]
Reap[sow /@ x] // Last
```

> `{{{"b", "c", 12}, {"b", "c", 32}, {"b", "c", 11}}, {{"b", "d", 22}}}`